# how do I fix python file closing automatically when importing certain libraries?

Tags: import, pycharm

So I am trying to run some scripts just by opening the python file directly (not running through pycharm). However, when I import certain libraries (such as numpy or matplotlib) the terminal will close automatically, even if the program is waiting for user input. All of these scripts run without error in pycharm.

Here is an example of some imports that don't close the window automatically:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import math as m

input('press enter to return')
```

Here is an example of some imports that do close the window automatically:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as m
    
input('press enter to return')
```

What is going on here? I am relatively new to coding and so I think I might be missing something fundamental.

Comment: What are the errors that come up?

Comment: there are no errors. when opening the .py files by clicking on them they just close automatically.

Comment: This code works perfectly fine for me, do you use an IDE? try it one pythons IDLE

Comment: the code with the numpy and matplotlib imports in IDLE closes automatically too. I was using pycharm to write these scripts.

Comment: thats actually weird, have you tried installing and uninstalling python maybe? or the libraries?

Comment: I uninstalled everything and reinstalled anaconda and I am still getting the same issue. Before I had both a python application and python w/in anaconda, could this have caused an issue?

Comment: It could be such that on anaconda, numpy or matplotlib wasnt installed? Try the normal version of python?

Comment: so reinstalling anaconda and checking the path option in the installation seemed to fix the issue. I think before I had not specified all the the paths in anaconda in the environmental variable path.

Comment: Yeah you're fine to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because anaconda has not been installed to your system path, it's important to have python interpreter and IDE being set to PATH especially when you are working with libraries that are not pre-installed

Hope it cleared your doubts, if any errors, do let me know

Cheers